# Is this sentence right? If he had joined our team, we would win

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, mood

Is thsi sentence right? If he had joined our team, we would win.

Comment: Hi Ted, welcome to EL&U. Regrettably, I'm flagging this question for closure: proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this passage?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified and you include the research you've done. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can talk about a game that took place already:

> If he had joined our team, we would have won.

But he did not join your team, and you lost.

Or you can talk about an upcoming game:

> If he had joined our team, we would win.

But he did not join your team, and so you might not win this upcoming game.

Or you can talk about a present game that is ongoing:

> If he had joined our team, we would be winning.

But he did not join your team, and you are not winning this game.

The opportunity to join the team is already a thing of the past in all three cases. The consequence can be a thing of the past, of the present, or of the future.

Comment: This sentence was one of the three choices, which are supposed to be wrong,

Comment: It is probably in a test in which the author of the test is assuming that the consequences are also in the past.